# flutter: how to get data from db and using it through the whole app

Tags: flutter, state-management

I am so confused about state management.

Below is I pass down data through widgets.

```
List<AppUser> userList = List<AppUser>();
List<List<MessageType>> messageLists = new List<List<MessageType>>();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    loadUsers();
  }

Future<void> loadUsers() async {
    userList.clear();
    userList.addAll(await AppUser.getRelatedUsers(customer.customerID));

    defaultUser = await AppUser.getDefaultUser(customer.customerID);

    if (defaultUser != null && !await defaultUser.hideUserTab()) {
      userList.add(defaultUser);
    }

  await loadMessageList();
  }
```

Then I pass the userList and messageList to another stateful widget. But what if I want to have those data through the whole app using inherited widget or provider or bloc.

```
 MessageTypePage(
      messageTypeList: messageLists[tabIndex],
      currentUser: userList[tabIndex],
    );
```

How can I possible to get the data from db and store them in inherited widget then using those data? I am so confused.

```
class StateContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final List<AppUser> userList;
  final List<Message> messageList;

  StateContainer({@required this.child, this.userList, this.messageList});

  static StateContainerState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedStateContainer>().data;
   
  }

  @override
  StateContainerState createState() => new StateContainerState();
}

class StateContainerState extends State<StateContainer> {
  List<AppUser> userList = List<AppUser>();
  List<List<MessageType>> messageLists = new List<List<MessageType>>();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _InheritedStateContainer(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class _InheritedStateContainer extends InheritedWidget {

  final StateContainerState data;

  _InheritedStateContainer({Key key, @required this.data, @required Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_InheritedStateContainer oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [State Management Approaches in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options). I personally use BLoC, because (after a short learning phase) it is easy to use and makes the process of state management simple.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best approach is to use Provider or Bloc. There is a flutter codelab that uses Provider to do something very similar to what you are doing. It stores a list of items (in your case that would be Users) that can be used throughout the app. It also shows you how to manipulate the list in various ways.

[The codelab is here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-cupertino/#0). I think it would help you out.